# LINQ value query returns wrong string

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've been making a chat program. I am doing the nickname function and I want the program to get the value of the `nick` element in the settings file. However, when I run the program, it returns the type of the string, not the value of it. The output is `Your current nickname is System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,<>f__AnonymousType01[System.String]]` when it is supposed to be the value of:

```
<ilanChat>
    <settings>
        <nick>User</nick>
    </settings>
</ilanChat>
```

The code is:

```
public string GetNick()
{
    string temp = "hello";
    ClientClass prog = new ClientClass();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(prog.settingsFile);
    var data = from item in doc.Descendants("settings")
               select new
               {
                   nick = item.Element("nick").Value
               };
    foreach (var i in data)
    {
        temp = data.ToString();
        temp = temp.Replace("{ name = ", "");
        temp = temp.Replace("}", "").Trim();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

but it returns the aforementioned problem. I also tried adding `temp` to a List, then returning the `[0]` value, but still problem.

Comment: I think you want `i.ToString()` rather than `data.ToString()`.

Answer (score 4):

You're intending to find a single string, but you're both wrapping that in an anonymous object as well as the fact that you have a *sequence* of zero to many items, not just one item.

First, don't use an anonymous object, just select out the string value.

Next, if you want just one item, not a sequence, you'll need to decide what item you want.  Do you want the first item?  Then use a method such as `FirstOrDefault` to get that one item.

```
var data = (from item in doc.Descendants("settings")
            select item.Element("nick").Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
return data;
```

Comment: this even doesn't compile :P

Comment: well, the `Deafult`? :P

Comment: @KingKing Right, thanks.  In the future you can just edit things like that.

Comment: This will throw a `NullReferenceException` on a missing `<nick>` element; I think returning `null` in that case would be more sensible.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I suppose it depends on the situation.  If having a `settings` element without a `nick` is valid, then yes, that would need to be accounted for.  If such a situation is an invalid file, it may be *desirable* to throw an exception, rather than ignoring the problem.

Comment: @Servy I agree in principle, but such an exception should give a more specific indication of the problem.  Allowing a `NullReferenceException` to propagate strikes me as poor design.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Sure.  When writing SO answers it's somewhat uncommon to validate input and throw the appropriate exceptions, but that's what should probably be done in production code.

Comment: True.  I only commented because the presence of `FirstOrDefault()` indicates you want to select `null` if the element is missing.  Here, you throw if `<nick>` is missing, but return `null` if `<settings>` is missing, which seems bizarre.  Why not just `select (string)item.Element("nick")` to return `null` in either case?

Comment: I dislike relying on the explicit conversion form `XElement` to string.  Conceptually you're getting its value, not converting the whole element.  Were I to write the code to return null in such a case I would do so differently. As to why it doesn't throw if settings is missing, it's merely an interpretation that settings is optional, but the `nick` isn't.  If that assumption is incorrect throwing an exception if `settings` isn't there may be desired. The exact semantics of all cases are easy enough to write out, but which is best is simply dependent on the specific context. I just picked one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference `i` rather than `data` in your loop.  Also, rather than converting the anonymous object `.ToString` and parsing that, just reference the anonymous property `nick` directly:

```
foreach (var i in data)
{
    temp = i.nick;
}
return temp;
```

If you're intending there to always be only a single value, then there's no need for a loop either.  Just grab the result directly with LINQ:

```
return data.Single().nick;
```

Comment: Such a `foreach` loop is rather nonsensical.  You may as well just call `Last`; it would at least make the intentions clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find a single `<nick>` element directly beneath `<settings>`, you can greatly simplify your method:

```
public static string GetNick()
{
    ClientClass prog = new ClientClass();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(prog.settingsFile);
    return (string)doc.Descendants("settings").Elements("nick").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will simply return `null` if there is no matching value.  The other answers posted thus far will throw if the element is missing.

I do not delve into how you might deal with duplicate `<nick>` or `<settings>` tags, as the possibilities are numerous.  This solution takes a "first value wins" approach; a "last value wins" approach simply requires replacing `FirstOrDefault()` with `LastOrDefault()`.